# Vue.js: Child Component mutates state, parent displays property as undefined

Tags: vue.js, components, vuex, parent

I have a parent component that lists all the tasks:

```
<template>
  <div class="tasks-wrapper">
    <div class="tasks-header">
      <h4>{{ $t('client.taskListingTitle') }}</h4>
      <b-button variant="custom" @click="showAddTaskModal">{{ $t('client.addTask') }}</b-button>
    </div>
      <b-table
        striped
        hover
        :items="tasks"
        :fields="fields"
        show-empty
        :empty-text="$t('common.noResultsFound')">
      </b-table>
    <AddTaskModal />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapActions, mapGetters } from 'vuex'
import AddTaskModal from '@/components/modals/AddTaskModal'
import moment from 'moment'

export default {
  name: 'TaskListing',
  components: {
    AddTaskModal
  },
  data () {
    return {
      tasks: [],
      fields: [
        { key: 'createdOn', label: this.$t('tasks.tableFields.date'), formatter: 'formatDate' },
        { key: 'domain', label: this.$t('tasks.tableFields.task') },
        { key: 'comment', label: this.$t('tasks.tableFields.comment') },
        { key: 'status', label: this.$t('tasks.tableFields.status') }
      ]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters('users', ['user'])
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions('tasks', ['fetchTasks']),
    ...mapActions('users', ['fetchUserById']),
    formatDate: function (date) {
      return moment.utc(date).local().format('DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm')
    },
    showAddTaskModal () {
      this.$bvModal.show('addTaskModal')
    }
  },
  async mounted () {
    const currUserId = this.$router.history.current.params.id
    if (this.user || this.user.userId !== currUserId) {
      await this.fetchUserById(currUserId)
    }
    if (this.user.clientNumber !== null) {
      const filters = { clientReferenceNumber: { value: this.user.clientNumber } }
      this.tasks = await this.fetchTasks({ filters })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Inside this component there is a child which adds a task modal.

```
<template>
  <b-modal
    id="addTaskModal"
    :title="$t('modals.addTask.title')"
    hide-footer
    @show="resetModal"
    @hidden="resetModal"
  >
    <form ref="form" @submit.stop.prevent="handleSubmit">
      <b-form-group
        :invalid-feedback="$t('modals.requiredFields')">
        <b-form-select
          id="task-type-select"
          :options="taskTypesOptions"
          :state="taskTypeState"
          v-model="taskType"
          required
        ></b-form-select>
        <b-form-textarea
          id="add-task-input"
          :placeholder="$t('modals.enterComment')"
          rows="3"
          max-rows="6"
          v-model="comment"
          :state="commentState"
          required />
      </b-form-group>
      <b-button-group class="float-right">
        <b-button variant="danger" @click="$bvModal.hide('addTaskModal')">{{ $t('common.cancel') }}</b-button>
        <b-button @click="addTask">{{ $t('modals.addTask.sendMail') }}</b-button>
      </b-button-group>
    </form>
  </b-modal>
</template>

<script>
import { mapActions, mapGetters } from 'vuex'

export default {
  name: 'AddTaskModal',
  data () {
    return {
      comment: '',
      commentState: null,
      taskTypesOptions: [
        { value: null, text: this.$t('modals.addTask.taskType') },
        { value: 'OnBoarding', text: 'Onboarding' },
        { value: 'Accounts', text: 'Accounts' },
        { value: 'TopUp', text: 'Topup' },
        { value: 'Overdraft', text: 'Overdraft' },
        { value: 'Aml', text: 'Aml' },
        { value: 'Transfers', text: 'Transfers' },
        { value: 'Consultation', text: 'Consultation' },
        { value: 'TechnicalSupport', text: 'TechnicalSupport' },
        { value: 'UnblockPin', text: 'UnblockPin' },
        { value: 'Other', text: 'Other' }
      ],
      taskType: null,
      taskTypeState: null
    }
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters('users', ['user']),
    ...mapGetters('tasks', ['tasks'])
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions('tasks', ['addNewTask', 'fetchTasks']),
    ...mapActions('users', ['fetchUserById']),
    async addTask (bvModalEvt) {
      bvModalEvt.preventDefault()
      if (!this.checkFormValidity()) { return }
      const currUserId = this.$router.history.current.params.id
      if (this.user || this.user.userId !== currUserId) {
        await this.fetchUserById(currUserId)
      }
      const data = {
        clientPhone: this.user.phoneNumber,
        comment: this.comment,
        clientReferenceNumber: this.user.clientNumber,
        domain: this.taskType
      }
      await this.addNewTask(data)
      if (this.user.clientNumber !== null) {
        const filters = { clientReferenceNumber: { value: this.user.clientNumber } }
        this.tasks = await this.fetchTasks({ filters })
        // this.tasks may be useless here
      }
      console.log(this.tasks)
      this.$nextTick(() => { this.$bvModal.hide('addTaskModal') })
    },
    checkFormValidity () {
      const valid = this.$refs.form.checkValidity()
      this.commentState = valid
      this.taskTypeState = valid
      return valid
    },
    resetModal () {
      this.comment = ''
      this.commentState = null
      this.taskTypeState = null
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

When I add a task I call getalltasks to mutate the store so all the tasks are added. Then I want to render them. They are rendered but the property createdOn on the last task is InvalidDate and when I console log it is undefined.

The reason I need to call gettasks again in the modal is that the response on adding a task does not return the property createdOn. I do not want to set it on the front-end, I want to get it from the database.

I logged the store and all the tasks are added to the store.

Why is my parent component not rendering this particular createdOn property?

If I refresh the page everything is rendering fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you add anything into a list of items that are displayed by v-for, you have to set a unique key. Based on your explanation, I assume that your key is the index and when you add a new item, you mess with the current indexes. Keys must be unique and unmutateable. What you need to do is to create a unique id for each element.

```
{
  id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000000)
}
```

When you create a new task, use the same code to generate a new id, and use id as key. If this doesn't help, share your d-table and related vuex code too.

Comment: I don't see what this has anything to do with this. The element is added but the date is only messed up. It has nothing with ids. Ids are random guids from the db.